# How to make my if statement shorter in python?

Tags: python

I'm really new to python. 
I'm trying to write an if statement but from how I see it, it looks like I have to write a lot of if statements. How can I make this shorter?

This is what  I have written:

```
user = input("Enter a note: ")
user_scale = scales[user]

if user_scale == Cscale:
    print (user_scale, '\n', "Relative scale: ", Amin_scale)
```

Now instead of writing another if statement, I want the C and Amin scale to be in one if statement. So that when ever the user inputs "C" or "Amin" it displays from the same if statement. Not sure if what I'm saying makes sense?

```
if user_scale == Amin_scale:
    print (user_scale, '\n', "Relative scale: ", Cscale)
```

Is there a way to write this in a much shorter way so that I don't have a whole lot of if statements?

---

Also I would like to make the user input as a while loop so that it keeps asking until I decide to quit but when I make it into a while loop it only executes the user_scale.

This is what I tried:

```
var = 1
while var == 1:
    user = input("what scale? ")
    user_scale = scales[user]
    print (user_scale)
```

update:
I'm trying to write a program that shows the user input scale and the relative scale. Example: if user type "C" then the program would show 
'C D E F G A B' and the Relative scale of C which is the Amin "A B C D E F G".

Comment: Why do you print `Admin_scale` if user scale is a `Cscale` and vice versa?

Comment: Are you asking for a `switch` statement?

Comment: how about the very *english* `or`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Elements not hashable

You can construct a list of tuples (or if the elements are *hashable* a dictionary) that stores for every scale, its relative scale. For instances:

```
scales = [(Cscale, Amin_scale), (Amin_scale, Cscale)]
```

Next we can iterate over it and check whether `user_scale` is the left element of a tuple, in that case, we print the right element of the tuple:

```
for left, right in scales:
    if user_scale == left:
        print (user_scale, '\n', "Relative scale: ", right)
```

## Elements are hashable (faster)

In case the elements are hashable, we can construct a dictionary and query it with `.get()`:

```
scales = {Cscale: Amin_scale, Amin_scale: Cscale}
right = scales.get(user_scale)
if right is not None:
    print (user_scale, '\n', "Relative scale: ", right)
```

Comment: I like your use of tuples here but I will make scales a dict not a list, for quick access to elements.

Comment: @VMRuiz: that's what the answer discusses: in case the elements are *hashable* (not guaranteed, since we do not know what these are), we can use a dictionary (that is the second approach).

Comment: Keys seems to be strings which are hashables, but I like your approach. Have my upvote

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say without fully-knowing your application. As far as I can see you are matching a scale with their relative scale. Then you could just use to different dicts:

```
user = input("Enter a note: ")
user_scale = scales[user]
relative_scale = relative_scales[user]
print (user_scale, '\n', "Relative scale: ", relative_scale)
```

`relative_scales` will contains the same keys from `scales` but with their correspondent relative scale.

Update: You can use Willem Van Onsem suggestion of using tuples and define only one dict which contains pairs of scales

```
user_scale, relative_scale = scales[user] # (Cscale, Amin_scale)
```